# Concern with ((type*)0)->member in container_of macro

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I'm slightly confused with statement ((type*)0)->member in the expansion of Linux kernel's most discussed macro "container_of"

Why doesn't de-referencing of 0 in container_of macro doesn't give problem?
I thought (may be i'm wrong) since we typecast 0 to (type*), we don't have problem. But hold on, consider this :-

```
void irq_handler(void *ptr)
{
    struct my_struct *p = (struct my_struct *) ptr;
    ptr->my_member = 7;
    global_variable = ptr->my_another_member;
    ...
    ...
}
```

Suppose assume due to some memory corruption, my ptr becomes NULL, then kernel will certainly crash due to dereference of NULL pointer in this case?

Why this partiality or differentiation? or any of my understanding is wrong? Correct me please.

Comment: If you examine the macro closer, you will notice that the member is actually not used, as such, so no null-pointer dereference.

Comment: @Joachim As far as i understand, if we use -> operator then it means we are dereferencing, right?

Comment: Yes, but like I say in my answer to the other question, it's used in a `typeof` construct which is resolved at _compile time_. The pointer is never referenced during run time.

Comment: You can see an explanation at [Wikipedia - offsetof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offsetof) and [linux kernel monkey log - container_of()](http://www.kroah.com/log/linux/container_of.html).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks for the quick responses.Now it is clear.

Comment: @OlafDietsche Thanks, its pretty much clear for me now.