# How to understand "((size_t) &((TYPE *)0)->MEMBER)"?

Tags: c, kernel

the codes in linux-2.6.16/include/linux/stddef.h is:

```
 #undef offsetof
 #ifdef __compiler_offsetof
 #define offsetof(TYPE,MEMBER) __compiler_offsetof(TYPE,MEMBER)
 #else
 #define offsetof(TYPE, MEMBER) ((size_t) &((TYPE *)0)->MEMBER)
 #endif

#define DNAME_INLINE_LEN (sizeof(struct dentry)-offsetof(struct dentry,d_iname))
```

How to understand "((size_t) &((TYPE *)0)->MEMBER)"?
Thank you

Comment: This is possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850265/concern-with-type0-member-in-container-of-macro

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The sequence of operations can be illustrated in the following way:

```
    1.                         0
    2.                ((TYPE *)0)
    3.              ( ((TYPE *)0)->MEMBER )
    4.             &( ((TYPE *)0)->MEMBER )
    5.  ( (size_t) &( ((TYPE *)0)->MEMBER )
```

1. Everything starts with number `0`.
2. `0` is cast to a pointer to `struct TYPE`.  IOW, we are making the compiler believe that there is such a `struct` at the beginning of the program's data segment (which is generally dangerous, but I'll mention later why not in this particular case).
3. Then, member `MEMBER` within this `struct` is referenced.
4. Its contents are not used, but its address taken (with `&`),
5. And this address converted back to a numeric type `size_t`.

As the address for the "start" of the struct was specified as `0`, the address of `MEMBER` (when converted to a number) is its offset within the struct.

The reason why this particular code is innocuous is that no memory position is ever written, not even accessed.  Everything involves just pointers to those positions (but not their contents) and numbers.  All of them held in machine registers or the usual local stack.

The following expression:

```
      ( (size_t) &( ((TYPE *)3264)->MEMBER ) - 3264 )
```

would also work.  3264 stands for any number of your choosing.  Added a parentheses set to make it more legible.

Comment: The reason this code is safe is not that no memory position is ever written, it's because no memory position is ever _accessed_.

Comment: @This isn't my real name:  That actually depends on the particular computer architecture the program is running on.  However, you are right as the question refers to Linux.

Comment: I'm not clear on what it is that you think depends on the architecture. You get undefined behavior if you read from that pointer, regardless. The calculation is safe because it's purely a question of math and nothing attempts to actually read the memory in question.

Comment: @This isn't my real name:  Yes, that's exactly my point in the original answer.  However, my reply is regarding your assertion that the code is safe because no memory position is ever accessed.  This is what I'm saying depends on architecture, and this is precisely why the language itself makes behaviour "undefined" (instead of "erroneous".  Under OSs without memory protection I have used this technique to read (and write) directly to video card memory in a consistent and predictable way.  The behaviour would be completely different in a different OS/video card ("architecture").

Answer (score 3):

This is a hack that lets you emulate the functionality of [`offsetof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof) when there is no support by the compiler: it exploits the fact that the address of the `MEMBER` equals its offset when the base address is set to zero.

Consider this example:

```
struct Test {
    char text[32];
    int count;
}
```

If `struct Test` is allocated at the address `0xC000`, then the address of `text` would be `0xC000`, and the address of `count` would be `0xC020`. However, if the base address is zero (which is not allowed by the standard), then the address of `text` would be zero, and the address of the count would be `0x20`. Casting these addresses to `size_t` gives you the offset of the corresponding members.

Answer (score 0):

It returns the offset of the specified structure member by basing it off of address 0. First it casts address 0 to the right type (that's the `(TYPE*)` cast) and then it adds the offset of the specified member to that base address. Since the base address is 0, you effectively get the offset of the member you specify in the macro.